# Append Multiple Attributes coming from JSON to a Anchor tag in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, json, spring, thymeleaf

Is there any way to append attributes coming in a single string from JSON to a anchor tag in thymeleaf?

if the attributes are separate we can iterate and assign attributes, but in this case all the attributes comes from same json field.

**Example:**
JSON:

```
{
linkAttrs = " href=\"https://website.com\" attr1=\"abc\" attr2=\"value\" attr3=\"\" "
}
```

Append to Link Like:

```
<a + ${json.linkAttrs}+>LinkText</a>
```

Expected Output:

```
<a href="https://website.com" attr1="abc" attr2="value" attr3="">LinkText</a>
```

Comment: how about to implement a custom AttrProcessor

Comment: Not planning to add additional processors or processing logic!

Comment: Have you tried `<a th:attrappend="${json.linkAttrs}">` ? Maybe you will need to make them comma separated in your controller to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<th:block th:utext="|<a ${json.linkAttrs}>LinkText</a>|" />
```